# Cannot update from Catalina to Big Sur on compatible Mac: "The requested version of macOS is not available"

Tags: macos, catalina, software-update, big-sur

I want to update from macOS Catalina to macOS Big Sur on a supported MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014).

Yet `System Preferences > Software Update` shows “Your Mac is up to Date - macOS Catalina 10.15.7”.

The App Store says macOS Big Sur “Works on this MacBook Pro”.

When I click the “GET” button, `System Preferences > Software Update` opens and says: “Update not found. The requested version of macOS is not available.”

[image: macOS Big Sur Update not found]

I found here [a similar question regarding updating to a prior version of macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366141/the-requested-version-of-macos-is-not-available-macos-catalina) but could not apply any of the answers successfully.

What can I do to update to macOS Big Sur?

**UPDATE:**
macOS 11.1 was just released, and now I am offered to update!

Comment: I'm facing same issue with Macbook Pro (15inch, 2019). Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue with MacBook Pro (15 inch, 2018), which is on the compatibility list: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to update to Big Sur came back with the release of 11.1.

In the comments [an article was mentioned that reported that 11.0.1 might have been intentionally blocked for certain MacBook Pro models because it caused lasting damage](https://mrmacintosh.com/big-sur-11-0-1-20b50-released-to-block-install-for-2013-14-13-mbpros/) (Thank you @Tetsujin & @bmike):

> Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B50) was released to block 2013 & 2014 13″ MBPro’s from installing the OS. This move looks to be related to the Big Sur install problems with these models.

Comment: I did not install it yet, because I depend upon this Mac for business and cannot risk any drama before Christmas.

Comment: Wise person move - there’s enough drama to last several months for many. Enjoy your Christmas break!

Answer (score 1):

For the time Big Sur was the latest so, the rest of this answer applied.  Now that Monterey is the current, best to go to [how to install previous versions of macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/5472) if you need Big Sur specifically and not the latest os.

If you use Safari and go to the Big Sur page, it will redirect to Monterey now.

- https://www.apple.com/macos/big-sur/

I recommend that unless your Mac can’t run the latest - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238

[Click the update now link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132).  I’m guessing it replicates your error and you need to then contact Apple support to get them to [fix their documentation or fix their links](https://mrmacintosh.com/big-sur-11-0-1-20b50-released-to-block-install-for-2013-14-13-mbpros/).

It’s on good authority that the update 11.1 resolves this and typically people will see that installer in less than 24 hours from release.

- https://mrmacintosh.com/whats-new-in-the-macos-big-sur-11-1-update-20c69/

Comment: The “Update now” link in Safari brings me to the Big Sur App Store page, there I can click “GET” and then I land where I had been before: In System Preferences > Software Update: “Update not found. The requested version of macOS is not available.”. But it was worth a try. Thank you.

Comment: Only @Apple can really make changes to their update catalog. I recall discussion if the installers were pulled for some specific models like 2013 and 2014 MacBook Pro but don’t have a solid link to share at present.

Comment: Weren't 13" 2014 Macs just removed from the compatibility list, because of the bricking issue? https://mrmacintosh.com/big-sur-11-0-1-20b50-released-to-block-install-for-2013-14-13-mbpros/

Comment: @Tetsujin This could be the answer. Do you want to add it as proper answer? Because I remember having been offered to update before, but I did not have the time for it, and now, it is no longer available. This would make sense. The only one who did not get the memo is the App Store which still says: “Works on this MacBook Pro”.

Comment: As bmike, says, there seems to be no official word on this - the Macs are still listed on the [Apple site](https://support.apple.com/HT211238) as compatible, which makes me uncomfortable making it into a real answer :/

Comment: Mr. Macintosh is always worth a read and edit to reference what they wrote IMO - this will clearly play out in time, but I get being impatient. Maybe install it in a VM if you need to run it meanwhile @MartinW

Comment: **UPDATE:** macOS 11.1 was just released, and now I am offered to update! But after your comments I am now reluctant to try it...

Comment: "If you use Safari and go to this link, what happens?" -- I am offered **Monterey**. But I need Big Sur.... (on a 2014 Mac Mini which _is_ supported by Big Sur.

Comment: [See my edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/5472) @LaryxDecidua thanks!